# How can I generate java heap usage graph from log file?

Tags: java

I'm dealing with OOME of our company's service, and now I have hprof and gc.log file.
I'd like to see the change of each heap space's usage, just like the image below.

[image]

But I don't know how I can get such a graph.
MAT doesn't have such a feature. I know some other GUI analysis tool, but they are only for real-time monitoring, not for generating graph from existing log file.
Anyone knows other good way?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a memory dump file try jvisualvm, some additional plugins may help with more insights i.e. https://dzone.com/articles/visualvm-gcviewer-plugin